# update on inner join of 2 tables with where clause

Tags: mysql, sql-update, inner-join

I am trying to do an update on an inner join of 2 tables with a where clause.
I currently have a select that get's the results I want to update. But I keep getting an error while trying to do the update.
Here is my SELECT that works :

```
SELECT a.rd_1, total_points 
FROM bracket.ticket as a
Inner join bracket.picks as b 
where 
b.team_ID = 31 AND a.ID = b.ticket_ID
```

And here is my update that doesn't work

```
UPDATE a 
set a.rd_1 = a.rd_1 + 1 
FROM bracket.ticket as a
Inner join bracket.picks as b 
    where 
    b.team_ID = 31 AND a.ID = b.ticket_ID
```

I have also tried this:

```
UPDATE a 
SET a.rd_1 = a.rd_1 + 1 
FROM bracket.ticket as a
Inner join bracket.picks as b 
    on a.ID = b.ticket_ID
where 
b.team_ID = 31 AND a.ID = b.ticket_ID
```

There error I get here is:
Syntax error: 'FROM' (from) is not a valid input at this position.

### ticket

ID | rd_1 | total_points

### picks

ID | ticket_ID | team_ID

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the correct syntax in MySQL:

```
UPDATE bracket.ticket t INNER JOIN
       bracket.picks p
       ON t.ID = p.ticket_ID
    SET t.rd_1 = t.rd_1 + 1 
WHERE p.team_ID = 31;
```

Your syntax looked more like SQL Server.

Note:  I changed the table aliases to be abbreviations for the table.  Meaningful table aliases (such as abbreviations) make the query more understandable.

Comment: This has the same issue

Comment: @SariRahal . . . This cannot.  There is no `FROM` (although there was for about 10 seconds because of a typo).

Comment: Sorry I made a mistake.  you are correct.  I copied and pasted wrong.

Comment: It does work. I will give you the correct answer when it allows me to.